# Prove that a convergent real sequence always has a smallest or a largest term

Tags: sequences-and-series

**My attempt:**

Suppose not, i.e., suppose there exists a convergent sequence $(a_n)$ that does not have a smallest or largest term.
$\implies (a_n)$ is bounded sequence.
$\implies A=\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
$\implies \sup{A},\inf{A}$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$.
Now, we need to show that at least one of $\sup{A},\inf{A}\in A$.
Equivalently, we need to show that the following case is impposible:
"Both $\sup{A}\notin A$ and $\inf{A}\notin A$".

I don't know how to proceed or if I am working it out correctly.

Comment: Take some local max/min you find, and consider the limit. If the limit is different from this local max/min, consider $\delta$ less than the difference, and find the point in the sequence where all elements are within $\delta$ of the limit. What does this tell you?

Comment: If it doesn't have a largest term, it must have an infinite strictly increasing subsequence.  If it doesn't have a smallest term, it must have an infinite strictly decreasing subsequence.  Such a sequence can't converge.

Comment: @saulspatz, this argument requires $A$ to be infinite set and further, the argument says there exists an increasing sequence in $A$ converging to $\sup{A}$. Such sequence need not be subsequence of $(a_n)$, as far as I know.

Comment: @DonThousand, Your comment is hard for me to follow. Could you be more precise please?

Comment: If we can always inductively create subsequence of $(a_n)$ that converges to $\sup{A}$, then I am done. I just want to confirm this fact.

Comment: If there is no largest term, then there must be a term larger than $a_1.$  Call it $a_{n_1}$.  Then there must be an $n_2>n_1$ such that $a_{n_2}>a_{n_1}$, for otherwise, the largest term of the sequence occurs among $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{n_1}$.  And so on.

Comment: @spkakkar:  any finite sequence has a largest and smallest term, so your question requires an infinite sequence.

Comment: Thanks @saulspatz for the detailed argument. You might right it as answer, so that I could accept it. Thanks all for their valuable time.

Comment: I think the negative of "has a smallest *or* a largest term" is "does not have a smallest term *and* does not have a largest term".  For example $f(n)=\frac1{1+n^2}$ converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ but does not have a smallest term

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$A:=${$a_n| n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$}

Since $a_n$ is convergent, it is bounded,

$S:= \sup A$, $I:=\inf A$ exist.

Assume $S, I \not \in A$.

1)$ \sup A \not = \inf A$ ;

There exists a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ of $a_n$ converging  to $S$.

There exist a subsequence $a_{n_l}$ of $a_n$ converging to $I$.

Since $a_n$ is convergent every subsequence converges to the same limit.

A contradiction.

2) $S=I$ , and by assumption $S,I \not \in A$,

we have $I <a_n<S$ , i.e .

$I <S$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, for case-wise analysis.

Comment: spkakkar. Welcome.:)

Comment: The first contradiction is unnecessary. You started with $S \neq I$, then showed that $S = I$ without using your assumption.

Comment: Wood. Don't get your point.

Comment: @Wood Is your idea to delete the lines "1) $\sup A \neq \inf A$" and "Hence a contradiction"?

Comment: @DavidK Exactly!

Answer (score 10):

Let $c=\sup A$ and $d=\inf A$. If these values are not attained by the sequence then there is a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ strictly increasing  to $c$ and a subsequence $a_{m_k}$ strictly decreasing to $d$. But the sequence is convergent so we must have $c=d$. But then $a_n$ is independent of $n$ contradicting the assumption that sup and inf are not reached.

Comment: I love this answer, and voted for it! But I think it's not written in an entirely correct way. Since you start with "If these values are not attained by the sequence", you must reach a contradiction, instead of concluding that "$a_n$ is independent of $n$". --- I would add "This implies $d<c$." after your second sentence, and change your third sentence to "But the sequence is convergent so we must have $c=d$, a contradiction."

Answer (score 1):

**Case $\bf{1}$:**

If there is a $k$ so that $a_k\lt\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$, then $\inf\limits_{n\ge0}a_n\lt\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$. Since the limit exists, there is an $n_0$ so that
$$
n\ge n_0\implies a_n\ge L=\frac12\left(\inf_{n\ge0}a_n+\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)\tag1
$$
Thus, there are only a finite number of terms where $a_n\lt L$. Since an infimum over a compact set is attained, there must be an $n_1$ so that $a_{n_1}=\inf\limits_{n\ge0}a_n$.

That is, the infimum is attained.

**Case $\bf{2}$:**

If there is a $k$ so that $a_k\gt\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$, then $\sup\limits_{n\ge0}a_n\gt\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$. Since the limit exists, there is an $n_0$ so that
$$
n\ge n_0\implies a_n\le L=\frac12\left(\sup_{n\ge0}a_n+\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)\tag2
$$
Thus, there are only a finite number of terms where $a_n\gt L$. Since a supremum over a compact set is attained,  there must be an $n_1$ so that $a_{n_1}=\sup\limits_{n\ge0}a_n$.

That is, the supremum is attained.

**Case $\bf{3}$:**

If neither Case $1$ nor Case $2$ hold, then for all $k$, $a_k=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$.

That is, both supremum and infimum are attained.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is convergent, hence bounded; if $q=\sup\{a_n:n\ge0\}$ and $p=\inf\{a_n:n\ge0\}$, then we know that $l=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\in[p,q]$. The case $p=q$ is obvious, so we can assume $p<q$.

Suppose $l>p$. Then, for $n>N$, $a_n>(l+p)/2>p$ and so $p=\inf\{a_n:0\le n\le N\}$ is actually a minimum.

Similarly, if $l<q$.